# I cant move on my branch Day_2

Tags: github

```
$ git checkout Day_2
error: pathspec 'Day_2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I am trying to move my branch `Day_2` and want to add a file. But I failed several times.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a branch named `Day_2`. Are you sure you do? Are you on an OS with a case-insensitive filesystem like Windows?

Comment: The error says that there is no branch `Day_2`. Can you add the output of `git branch -a` to your question?